# How to specify app version in pm2 start via Yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I have a Node.js + Express application, let's call `myapp v0.3.0`, that I start with [Yarn scripts](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/), such as:

```sh
yarn prod
```

I've deployed my production application with [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/), using:

```sh
pm2 start yarn --name myapp -- prod
```

This works and the app is properly deployed, but when I look at `pm2 list`, the version of the PM2 application is *Yarn's version* (0.39.1), not `myapp`'s version (0.3.0):

```sh
┌────┬───────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬───┬────────┬─────┬────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name  │ namespace │ version │ mode │ pid    │ uptime │ ↺ │ status │ cpu │ mem    │ user │ watching │
├────┼───────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼───┼────────┼─────┼────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ 1  │ myapp │ default   │ 0.39.1  │ fork │ 124777 │ 43h    │ 1 │ online │ 0%  │ 49.2mb │ pm2  │ disabled │
└────┴───────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴───┴────────┴─────┴────────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

My CI/CD tool uses the `version` field from PM2 to manage automatic deployments. Is there a way to make the version track the application version (e.g. 0.3.0) instead of Yarn's version?

Answer (score 2):

Add yarnwrapper bash script in the same directory of your package.json:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "/${HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/$(node -v)/bin/yarn prod"
```

Launch it with pm2:

```
pm2 start yarnwrapper --name myapp --interpreter bash
```